# SqlDatasource: Parameters on Select()

Tags: c#, sqldatasource

After reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select(v=vs.110).aspx

I'm a bit confused about the Select() method of the SqlDatasource. It's easy to explain with an example. Let's consider this test code:

```
//sql is a SqlDatasource, let's get out the question the initialization.
sql.SelectCommand= "select * from employees where iddepartment = @iddeparment";
sql.SelectParameters.Add("iddepartment ", DbType.Int, "1");
```

At this point, I need to retrieve the data, so i try to do something like:

```
IEnumerable<object> myData = sql.Select();
```

However according to MSDN documentation, `Select` methods requieres 1 parameter of type `DataSourceSelectArguments`. This confuses me, Why do I have to pass some "Select parameters" as an argument if I already set them by calling `SelectParameter.Add(...)`? How can I call correctly this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DataSourceSelectArguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datasourceselectarguments(v=vs.110).aspx) is not what you thought it is. For your case, you can simply pass `DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty`.

> Data-bound controls use the DataSourceSelectArguments class to request
>   that a data source control performs additional data-related operations
>   on a result set, such as sorting the data or returning a specific
>   subset of data. These data-related operations are enumerated by the
>   DataSourceCapabilities enumeration. The following table indicates how
>   the DataSourceSelectArguments class supports these data-related
>   operations.

This parameter can contain information regarding the filters to apply or the column to Order By. For example, when working with a sortable GridView, sorting a column calls the Select() method, and passes in a DataSourceSelectArguments instance with its SortExpression property set to the column name the user chose to sort by. If you don't want the DataSource to sort or filter, you pass in DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty.